# Advantage of 3rd party connection pool

Tags: java, connection-pooling

With most of the application servers nowadays have their own connection pools built-in,
i.e. Tomcat 7 has The Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool, JBoss has its own, and so does Glassfish, Weblogic etc.

is there any advantage to use 3rd party connection pools such as dbcp or c3p0 ?

One advantage I can think of is the ease of war deployment maybe. what else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an application server's connection pool, will most likely, couple you to that specific application server.  Which means that if that specific implementation doesn't work for you, it might be difficult to change implementations in the future.

It also means that you will most likely not be able to run your application in anything but that specific application container.  Which will increase the potential difficulty for performing automated integration tests.

Hopefully, which ever connection pool you use will be abstracted so that you can plug in any connection pool you chose.  I think this is the general case anyways, but you might want to make sure.

I believe using springs jdbc templates would help to reduce coupling to a specific connection pool implementation.